# Using decorated OutputStream/InputStream fields in your class

Tags: java, stream, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, decorator

This question may seem a little trivial at first, but I am experiencing odd OutOfMemory problems since I began implementing this. After looking through the Java Heap Dumps, I know the memory leak is related to the ObjectOutputStream variable. Without further ado, here is the code:

In my constructor, I am setting up field variables that will hold my Input/Output Stream variables. Along with it, I am creating two other sets of variables for when I am specifically doing IO on custom objects and then pure primitives:

```
  public SingleServer(Socket s, int maxThreads) {
    client = s;
    serversCreated.incrementAndGet();
    try {
      is = client.getInputStream();
      os = client.getOutputStream();
      ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
      oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
      dis = new DataInputStream(is);
      dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // ...
    }
    print("Client Connected");

  }
```

Now, before, all there was was storage of OOS, the object output stream. So, you may have asking why I am going through the trouble of creating these fields? The answer is I wanted to separate the sending of primitives from the sending of custom objects vs the sending of pure bytes. I thought Java was okay in separating things out like this.

What I am noticing is that suddenly and hard-to-predictingly some objects now cause OutOfMemory Error's which crash my program. I know I can just forget about using all these different decorators for the IO classes, but I want to understand why these out of memory errors would happen?

- Is there something fundamentally wrong with decorating your IO stream multiple times?
- Is it better to decorate a stream on demand, before actually using it, and then let the garbage collector handle it when its no longer needed?
- As an extension to the above question, before when everything was working without memory errors, the only object I actually stored was OOS. Yet, now, the memory errors are related to OOS. Does the creation of DOS or OS cause the garbage collector to not run properly?

Comment: _Is there something fundamentally wrong with decorating your IO stream multiple times?_ Not if you write and read in the same order.

Comment: I assume the streams are being closed() properly in a finally block, and you just abstracted that away?

Comment: Well, no the streams don't get closed until the very end of the operations. The memory errors happen before then. --- If you could expand on your point though -- should I manually close and re-open a steam at strategic points in the program?

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the same `InputStream` in two independent wrappers is an unsupported idiom. The first wrapper might immediately read some input to fill its buffer; the second one may try to do the same. Each wrapper is free (and even encouraged) to assume that it can fully read out its underlying stream, at its own discretion.

So, in a nutshell,

> Is there something fundamentally wrong with decorating your IO stream multiple times?

Yes, there is.

Comment: This was an answer I was looking for, however do you have a reference to that?

Comment: Also -- what about my original goal? I wanted a separate IO field variable for the streams holding primitives, vs custom objects, vs bytes (and eventually Zip streams). How can I combine them all most efficiently?  I'm almost thinking I make the new decorated streams on-demand each time and close them after I do my writes/reads. Only keeping the original OutputStream/InputStream variable alive.

Comment: You can prepare a byte array in memory with a `ByteArrayOutputStream` wrapped appropriately, then write out that array to the raw client output stream. But doing the same on the reading side is not as straightforward.

Comment: Well I'm considering gong back to just using the Object IO Streams, as each object I am working with is serializable anyway.

Comment: Did you notice that ObjectInput/OutputStreams support reading/writing primitive values as well?

Comment: I do. I'm not sure why but I assumed the Object IO Stream would have more overhead involved. I figured its best to use the decorator that specializes in primitives

Comment: DataIn/Outputstreams were introduced in JDK 1.0, and ObjectIn/OutStreams appeared in JDK 1.1. So you can just look at them as "new and improved" :)

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as an 'unsupported idiom'. It's just an idiom that can't work.