# Is it posible to send primary type and byte array in same stream over socket

Tags: java, java-io

My broblem is:

I'm building a remote desktop application in java using tcp socket. I create a PrintWriter/Scanner stream on socket to exchange command of mouse, keyboard and screen resolution(primary type) between client and server, it work good. After that i create a DataOutputStream/DataInputStream on same socket to transfer screen shot(byte array) from client to server then my app cashed.

Can anyone help me to resolve this broblem, many thank!

Comment: Are the readers and writers closing?  If so, they might be closing the underlying stream as well.  Can you use dataoutputstream to send the mouse state, keyboard state, and screen resolution so that you don't have multiple writers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by 'primary type'. It's `DataOutputStream` that writes *primitive* types, if that's what you mean, not `BufferedWriter.` In this case you should use `DataOutputStream` for everything. There's no sense in converting things to strings for the wire via `BufferedWriter` only to have to parse them again at the other end with a `Scanner.` There's also a space cost. And finally you can't do it anyway because of the buffering issues.

Answer (score -1):

The same socket should not be used this way. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18449544/337621 . You could write the content of the PrintWriter into a ByteArrayOutputStream, and then you can write the content of it into the DataOutputStream as byte array. On client side you read the first byte array, you do the scanning on it as ByteArrayInputStream, then you read the second byte array, which will be your screenshot. I guess you need to write the size of the byte arrays to the DataOutputStream before the arrays as well.

Comment: The receiver can't identify the first byte array without more information than you have suggested sending here. None of this is even necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. If you look carefully, I have written, that the length of the byte array should be sent before the actual array. I don't think that it is big deal for the client to know, that metadata comes first, then the screenshot. Or to have an additional flag before the arrays. As for what "makes sense", he could simply use ObjectOutputStream+ObjectInputStream as well. Is not it true?

Comment: The ByteArrayOutputStream remains unnecessary, as does the `PrintWriter.` I don't know what the part about 'what makes sense' stuff is about. If it's a comment on my answer, it should appear below it.